# Ways to choose color theme of a website

Tags: javascript, css, class, colors, themes

On some websites you can choose a color theme of a website by clicking a button. Seems like nothing sophisticated, however is there any state of the art techniques to do that (maybe toggle between classes throughout a page or call different css files)?

Answer (score 0):

i find the new css3 solutions very helpfull also the js:

```
element.classList.add('className');
element.classList.remove('className');
element.classList.toggle('className');
element.classList.contains('className');// check first
```

and so if you want to change the whole page's style you need to start from the highest element as you can't style parent nodes with css ...

example 1

with more than 2 classes

```
body.class1{color:blue}
body.class1>div{color:blue}
body.class1>div>a>p>whatever:hover{color:blue}

body.class2{color:green}
body.class2>div{color:green}
/*the div's inside the body with class 'class2' have a green font*/
body.class2>div>a>p>whatever:hover{color:green}
```

in this case you change the style to the whole page by just calling

```
body.classList.remove('class1');
body.classList.add('class2');
```

example 2

with 2 classes (one default and extra)

```
body{color:blue}
body>div{color:blue}
body>div>a>p>whatever:hover{color:blue}

body.extra{color:green}
body.extra>div{color:green}
body.extra>div>a>p>whatever:hover{color:green}
```

js:

```
body.classList.toggle('extra');
```

you can also change the whole css.. depends on how much your really wanna change.

or create the rules dynamically with javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet.insertRule

```
myStyle.insertRule("#blanc { color: white }", 0);
```

but i think the first one is the simplest to handle...

also if you have a container which will be displayed as grid,rows large icons the simplest solution is just to create a class on the parent container.like in example 1.

tip:another thing i use alot lately is hsla (hue,saturation,lightness,alpha);

i use this if i want to have the background and the font the same color but the font just slightly darker:

```
background-color:hsla(360,100%,20%,1);// 20% light
color:hsla(360,100%,80%,1);// 80% light
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your body a color class.

For example `<body class="color-green">`. You can toggle the class via JS:

`document.body.classList.toggle('color-green')`.

In your CSS you have to create color-aware selectors:

```
.button {
  color: blue;
}

.color-green .button {
  color: green;
}
```

In my opinion that's the way to go.

*If you create a lot of color rules in your CSS you should probably seperate them into their own files and include them when the change-color button is clicked.*